# Dijkstra's not storing shortest path

Tags: java, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am having a problem with keeping the shortest path correct for my Dijkstra's algorithm. It correctly finds the shortest length and returns it (verified using actual output to correctly used algorithm) but the array being made is not correct. I believe this issue can be found when I am updating the arraylist. My code is as follows:

```
public static Double Dijkstras(String startVertexName,
        String endVertexName, ArrayList<String> shortestPath) {
    HashSet<String> S = new HashSet<String>();
    HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, Double> cost = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    cost.put(startVertexName, 0.0);
    for (String e : dataMap.keySet()) {
        if (e.compareTo(startVertexName) != 0) {
            cost.put(e, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
    while (!S.containsAll(dataMap.keySet())) {

        ArrayList<String> notInS = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String x : dataMap.keySet()) {
            if (!S.contains(x)) {
                notInS.add(x);
            }
        }
        Double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        String foundK = "this is not right";
        for (String k : notInS) {
            if (cost.get(k) < smallest) {
                smallest = cost.get(k);
                foundK = k;
            }
        }
        S.add(foundK);
        notInS.remove(foundK);
        HashSet<String> notInSAdjacent = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String g : adjacencies.get(foundK).keySet()) {
            if (notInS.contains(g)) {
                notInSAdjacent.add(g);
            }
        }
        String temp2 = "";
        for (String j : notInSAdjacent) {
            if ((cost.get(foundK) + adjacencies.get(foundK).get(j)) < cost
                    .get(j)) {
                cost.put(j,
                        cost.get(foundK) + adjacencies.get(foundK).get(j));
                temp2 = j;
            }
        }
        if (!temp.containsKey(temp2)) {
            shortestPath.add(foundK);
        } else {
            int index = shortestPath.indexOf(temp.get(temp2));
            shortestPath.remove(index);
            shortestPath.add(index, foundK);

        }
        temp.put(temp2, foundK);

        if (foundK.compareTo(endVertexName) == 0) {
            break;
        }

    }
    return cost.get(endVertexName);

}
```

Let me know if anyone can see a noticeable error. I can supply sample input and output if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample input and **expected** output.

Comment: Input/output would be helpful.  In particular the expected vs actual output.  Also, is this homework?

Comment: If you want a ready to use and well tested lib you can use GraphHopper